# Bootstrap datepicker not working jquery-1.8.2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi hay have a issue with the library of bootstrap datepicker or with my library jquery

```
enter code here
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Click me!">

<script>
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

My web console of firefox send my this exception when I click on my text box
String empty send to getElementById()  jquery-1.8.2.js

Please help

Answer (score 0):

When you call `datepicker()`, the document may not be loaded.
Call `datepicker()` when the document is loaded.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: @MenochAzrielRice try to change the input to `<input type="text" class="span2" value="02-16-2012" id="dp1" >` and call `$('#dp1').datepicker();`. It's from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: @MenochAzrielRice One more thing to check. Don't you forget including `bootstrap.js`?